# Multiple contextual filters with spaces

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-contextual-filters

I have a view with a contextual filter, which works fine - except that filter terms with spaces in don't work if I select 'Allow multiple values'. If I don't select this then the term with the spaces works fine. But I really need multiple values! Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Views 7 only support multiple values using TERM ID. A feature/support request has been created in Drupal.org forum.